# Is it possible to achive classic Z depth type fog or mist in the viewport (3D-view) in Blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

In Blender 2.79 there was a simple Z distance or depth type fog. We only have to turn on in the world panel the Mist option and fine tune the parameters. Ee could see it in the 3d-view.

[image]

Is there an equivalent in 2.8? I'm looking for the simpliest ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) solution. 
Or do we have to use the volumetrics in the 3d-view? I guess that is more complex and time consuming solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're asking about the viewport, looks like volumetrics is the only option for now. It's very fast though and easy if you attach the volume scatter to the world shader.

1. World tab, check "use nodes"
2. Shader (Node) editor, select world instead of object
3. Add volume scatter (try density between 0.01 and 0.1) and plug into volume world node.

Doesn't require volumetrics to be enabled in eevee tab; works better viewing with camera. A super-fast hack in the compositor, at least fast in terms of cpu time, using z buffer (z render output -> divide by a two to  four digit number, add a number between 0 and 1, mix with image render output using lighten or screen) doesn't affect the viewport and doesn't work with DOF.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there anyway that once you use the volume scatter node to create the fog/depth look to make the background transparent?

Comment: @J.Jesse yes, assuming since you're asking about alpha that you want to composite the render with another image source. Posted another answer below for your use case. Also check out the "holdout" shader node to create a "green screen," might be easier to alpha-out the backdrop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Mist is back as of 2.82a, enable mist in view layer properties: [image: View Layer Properties]

Invert the mist output and plug into alpha: [image: Composite Settings]

Which will give you alpha to overlay over other renders/photos. [image]
Obviously this example render looks terrible but shows mist-based alpha in action.

Comment: This doesn't work in the viewport, only in renders.